# Creating an app that has an option to get location information even when it's not running

Tags: android

What's the best way to create an app that periodically gets location (via the GPS or cell towers, or whatever) even when the app isn't running?

The first idea I had is to use the AlarmManager to wake up at a specified interval and check.  I'm wondering if there's a more specific API to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You subscribe to get notification on LocationChanged. You will get a broadcast receiver that will wake up your app. You can launch activities from the BroadCast receiver using the passed context as launchpoint.

```
locMan = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// loop through all providers, and register them to send updates
List<String> providers = locMan.getProviders(false);
for (String provider : providers) {
    Log.e("mytag", "registering provider " + provider);
    long minTimeMs = 5 * 60 * 1000;// 5 minute
    float minDistance = LOCATION_HOT_RADIUS_IN_METERS;
    locMan.requestLocationUpdates(provider, minTimeMs, minDistance,
            getIntent());
}

private PendingIntent getIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationReceiver.class);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
}
```

and the receiver

```
public class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.content.BroadcastReceiver#onReceive(android.content.Context,
 * android.content.Intent)
 */
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        Location loc = (Location) b
                .get(android.location.LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
        if (loc != null) {


        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: So, with this, the mMinTimeMs is a specification of how often you want to be notified?

Comment: Yeah you are right, read the documentation on those. http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html